# bootstrap classes Col-md-6 col-lg-6 not working(overflowing) in form-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two form-groups in which there is a label and input textbox. Both label and input textbox have class names *col-md-6 col-lg-6*. Since the text inside the labels are too long, tt is pushing the second label in to the second half (labels are pushing in to textbox columns). How can the labels be set on left half and input elements on right half (even if the labels are too long)?

```
    <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">

      <div className="form-group">

    <div className="form-inline"><Field name="no" component=    type="checkbox" /> No</div>                                             
       </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: is you className work?

Comment: Yes, That is in javascript but bootstrap applies

Comment: will you make it a workable jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** There is no HTML attribute called `className`, You have used it in all your elements.

**Solution:** change all the occurrences of the `className` to `class` and it must work.

---

*note*: `className` is used in **[Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)** for manipulating the `class` attribute of any given element.

Answer (score 0):

When creating HTML elements, use attribute `class` instead of `className`. [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is a property on DOM elements (in Javascript).

e.g.

```
<div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
```

Should be

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
```

See [this plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IgfimQeTIz6mASxnpnej?p=preview)